# How could i rename a file that is currently running in c#?

Tags: c#

so basically I want to be able to rename the file application by itself without saying an error that the application is running so it can't rename it. is it possible?

Comment: On Windows - the File is locked because the process is running. You can use a launcher type approach. Instead of using the exe directly have a launcher exe. Launcher will check if its own name is similar to the actual exe if not it renames it. From the running code (i.e. actual exe) you rename the launcher.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @MichaelRandall its for a bootstrapper so it can download the new file and replace with the new one

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:
lets say the actual exe is called file.exe

- Have another program called file_launcher.exe - whose job is to check that file.exe and its own name (string before the underscore) is same
- If not then it renames the file.exe appropriately
- Then it starts the actual exe (using new name)
- Actual exe when has to rename itself, actually renames the launcher file (updating the first part of name)

Comment: thank you for your time and the help, I tried it and it is working!